# Parentheses usage in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I was experimenting with setting the value of a variable

```sql
declare @tablename nvarchar(1000);

set @tablename = SELECT TOP 1 NAME FROM SYS.TABLES ORDER BY NAME; //Error
set @tablename = (SELECT TOP 1 @tablename = NAME FROM SYS.TABLES ORDER BY NAME;) //Works fine
```

What magic parentheses did here?

I guess it has to do with evaluation. But why it didn't evaluate in the first statement then?

Comment: The parantheses aren't "magic" it's making valid syntax. `SET @tablename =  SELECT...` isn't correct syntax and the parser will generate an error.

Comment: I didn't know the subquery needs it's own set of parantheses as the answer states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subquery requires its own set of parentheses.  So the second has valid syntax because it is using them.

You may be confused with `select` versus `set`.  You can set a parameter using `select` and no parentheses are needed:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @tablename = NAME
FROM SYS.TABLES
ORDER BY NAME;
```

Comment: I would like to know the internal working(the flow), why this works (using SELECT) and my example didn't. Can you suggest a source?

Comment: @Shad Ref: [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). "... | ( scalar_subquery ) |  ..."